# dart method calling context

Tags: scope, dart

I used the below to see how dart calls methods passed in to other methods to see what context the passed in method would/can be called under.

```dart
void main() {

  var one = new IDable(1);
  var two = new IDable(2);

  print('one ${caller(one.getMyId)}');             //one 1
  print('two ${caller(two.getMyId)}');             //two 2
  print('one ${callerJustForThree(one.getMyId)}'); //NoSuchMethod Exception

}

class IDable{
  int id;
  IDable(this.id);

  int getMyId(){
    return id;
  }
}

caller(fn){
  return fn();
}

callerJustForThree(fn){
  var three = new IDable(3);
  three.fn();
}
```

So how does `caller` manager to call its argument `fn` without a context i.e. `one.fn()`, and why does `callerJustForThree` fail to call a passed in `fn` on an object which has that function defined for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Dart there is a difference between an instance-method, declared as part of a class, and other functions (like closures and static functions).

Instance methods are the only ones (except for constructors) that can access `this`. Conceptually they are part of the class description and not the object. That is, when you do a method call `o.foo()` Dart first extracts the class-type of `o`. Then it searches for `foo` in the class description (recursively going through the super classes, if necessary). Finally it applies the found method with `this` set to `o`.

In addition to being able to invoke methods on objects (`o.foo()`) it is also possible to get a bound closure: `o.foo` (without the parenthesis for the invocation). However, and this is crucial, this form is just syntactic sugar for `(<args>) => o.foo(<args>)`. That is, this just creates a fresh closure that captures `o` and redirects calls to it to the instance method.

This whole setup has several important consequences:

- You can tear off instance methods and get a bound closure. The result of `o.foo` is automatically bound to `o`. No need to bind it yourself (but also no way to bind it to a different instance). This is way, in your example, `one.getMyId` works. You are actually getting the following closure: `() => one.getMyId()` instead.
- It is not possible to add or remove methods to objects. You would need to change the class description and this is something that is (intentionally) not supported.
- `var f = o.foo;` implies that you get a fresh closure all the time. This means that you cannot use this bound closure as a key in a hashtable. For example, `register(o.foo)` followed by `unregister(o.foo)` will most likely not work, because each o.foo will be different. You can easily see this by trying `print(o.foo == o.foo)`.
- You cannot transfer methods from one object to another. However you try to access instance methods, they will always be bound.

---

Looking at your examples:

```dart
  print('one ${caller(one.getMyId)}');             //one 1
  print('two ${caller(two.getMyId)}');             //two 2
  print('one ${callerJustForThree(one.getMyId)}'); //NoSuchMethod Exception
```

These lines are equivalent to:

```dart
 print('one ${caller(() => one.getMyId())}');
 print('two ${caller(() => two.getMyId())}');
 print('one ${callerJustForThree(() => one.getMyId())}';
```

Inside `callerJustForThree`:

```dart
callerJustForThree(fn){
  var three = new IDable(3);
  three.fn();
}
```

The given argument `fn` is completely ignored. When doing `three.fn()` in the last line Dart will find the class description of `three` (which is `IDable`) and then search for `fn` in it. Since it doesn't find one it will call the `noSuchMethod` fallback. The `fn` argument is ignored.

If you want to call an instance member depending on some argument you could rewrite the last example as follows:

```dart
main() {
  ...
  callerJustForThree((o) => o.getMyId());
}

callerJustForThree(invokeIDableMember){
  var three = new IDable(3);
  invokeIDableMember(three);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain, which is not necessarily a strength of mine. If something I wrote isn't understandable, feel free to give me a shout.

Think of methods as normal objects, like every other variable, too.

When you call `caller(one.getMyId)`, you aren't really passing a reference to the method of the class definition - you pass the method "object" specific for instance `one`.

In `callerJustForThree`, you pass the same method "object" of instance `one`. But you don't call it. Instead of calling the object `fn` in the scope if your method, you are calling the object `fn` of the instance `three`, which doesn't exist, because you didn't define it in the class.

Consider this code, using normal variables:

```dart
void main() {
  var one = new IDable(1);
  var two = new IDable(2);
  caller(one.id);
  caller(two.id);
  callerJustForThree(one.id);
}

class IDable{
  int id;
  IDable(this.id);
}

caller(param){
  print(param);
}

callerJustForThree(param){
  var three = new IDable(3);
  print(three.id); // This works
  print(param);   // This works, too
  print(three.param); // But why should this work?
}
```

It's exactly the same concept. Think of your callbacks as normal variables, and everything makes sense. At least I hope so, if I explained it good enough.

Comment: So does that mean that every instance of IDable is walking around with its own implementation of getMyId()? Isn't that weird and using up a lot of memory unnecessarily?

Comment: @0xor1 Depends. If you compile to JS, then yes, because it's JS. I don't think the Dart VM does this, because you can't change class methods at runtime. For an "under the hood" explanation, see Florian Loitsch's answer, who can explain this better by far.

Comment: Even in dart2js it will not have its own copy. The functionality is in the prototype and the bound closures are built in hidden getters.