# why does dart create closures when referencing a method?

Tags: closures, dart

```dart
void main() {
  A one = new A(1);
  A two = new A(2);

  var fnRef = one.getMyId;        //A closure created here
  var anotherFnRef = two.getMyId; //Another closure created here
}

class A{
  int _id;
  A(this._id);
  int getMyId(){
    return _id;
  }
}
```

According to the [dart language tour](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-function-equality) page referencing methods like this creates a new closure each time. Does anyone know why it does this? I can understand creating closures when defining a method body as we can use variables in an outer scope within the method body, but when just referencing a method like above, why create the closure as the method body isn't changing so it can't use any of the variables available in that scope can it? I noticed in a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450980/dart-method-calling-context) question I asked that referencing methods like this effectively binds them to the object they were referenced from. So in the above example if we call `fnRef()` it will behave like `one.getMyId()` so is the closure used just for binding the calling context? ... I'm confused :S

**UPDATE**

In response to Ladicek. So does that mean that:

```dart
void main(){
    var fnRef = useLotsOfMemory();
    //did the closure created in the return statement close on just 'aVeryLargeObj'
    //or did it close on all of the 'veryLargeObjects' thus keeping them all in memory 
    //at this point where they aren't needed
}

useLotsOfMemory(){
    //create lots of 'veryLarge' objects
    return aVeryLargeObj.doStuff;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ladicek is right: accessing a method as a getter will automatically bind the method.

In response to the updated question:

No. It shouldn't keep the scope alive. Binding closures are normally implemented as if you invoked a getter of the same name:

```dart
class A{
  int _id;
  A(this._id);
  int getMyId() => _id;

  // The implicit getter for getMyId. This is not valid
  // code but explains how dart2js implements it. The VM has
  // probably a similar mechanism.
  Function get getMyId { return () => this.getMyId(); }
}
```

When implemented this way you will not capture any variable that is alive in your `useLotsOfMemory` function.

---

Even if it really was allocating the closure inside the `useLotsOfMemory` function, it wouldn't be clear if it kept lots of memory alive.

Dart does not specify how much (or how little) is captured when a closure is created. Clearly it needs to capture at least the free variables of itself. This is the minimum. The question is thus: "how much more does it capture"?

The general consensus seems to be to capture every variable that is free in *some* closure. All local variables that are captured by some closure are moved into a context object and every closure that is created will just store a link to that object.

Example:

```dart
foo() {
  var x = new List(1000);
  var y = new List(100);
  var z = new List(10);
  var f = () => y;  // y is free here.
  // The variables y and z are free in some closure.
  // The returned closure will keep both alive.
  // The local x will be garbage collected.
  return () => z;  // z is free here.
}
```

I have seen Scheme implementations that only captured their own free variables (splitting the context object into independent pieces), so less is possible. However in Dart this is not a requirement and I wouldn't rely on it. For safety I would always assume that all captured variables (independent of who captures them) are kept alive. *I would also make the assumption that bound closures are implemented similar to what I showed above and that they keep a strict minimum of memory alive.*

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly right -- the closure captures the object on which the method will be invoked.